# Cocos2d-x - Acces sprite from other class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a program that is made from Lobby and DrawingCanvas.

In Lobby there is a button - when you click it, it goes to DrawingCanvas.
If you click it also a sprite appears. In DrawingCanvas there is Back button that makes you go to Lobby. I want to dissapear sprite from Lobby when you click Back button so you have clean Lobby without sprite. In Lobby I have:

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance() -> getVisibleSize();
cocos2d::Sprite* notification = cocos2d::Sprite::create("NotificationM.png");
notification -> setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
notification -> setScale(1.05);
notification -> setPosition(Vec2(150, visibleSize.height));
this -> addChild(notification);
notification -> setTag(99);
```

Everything is good here. The problem is in DrawingCanvas class.

```
void DrawingCanvas::bckPressed(Ref *pSender, ui::Widget::TouchEventType eEventType)
{
if (eEventType == ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED)
    {
        SceneManager::getInstance() -> returnToLobby(); 

        ? -> removeChildByTag(99);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to access Lobby class where is my sprite with tag 99 or access notification sprite from other class to hide it for example, not delete. :-(

Comment: declare notification sprite as static in Lobby class then it can be easily access by DrawingCanvas class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your *button* is a child of of *Lobby* (maybe not direct). So there are two basic approaches:

1. From button get to parent and call `getParent()->removeChildByTag(99)`
2. When creating a *button* make give it a callback with a function that you want to be called from *Lobby*

Second approach is a bit more complicated but more robust.

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't know how to delete Sprite from Lobby. I don't know how to do it from DrawingCanvas class. I don't know how to access Sprite from Lobby in **DrawingCanvas**. I put Question Mark in second code, I don't know what to write there.

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice the name of the class in second part. Then draw a tree of parent-child relations and connect them through a common parent.

Comment: sounds complicated ;-) any clues how to do this?

Comment: Just figure out who is the parent of Lobby and Drawing canvas. If no common ancestor - repeat for their parents and so on.